# play, scala and jerkson noClassDefFound error

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, jerkson

I am trying to work with jerkson in play and with scala 2.10.
However, i want to load data fixtures based on a json files. for this prcoedure I'm trying to load the json with the "`parse`" command from jerkson.
That ultimatly fails.

I'm doing this in the "`override def onStart(app: Application)`" function. The error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.codahale.jerkson.Json$
```

Any guesses why this is happening ? I have the following libs in my deps.:

```
"com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.5.0",
"com.cloudphysics" % "jerkson_2.10" % "0.6.3"
```

my parsing command is:

```
com.codahale.jerkson.Json.parse[Map[String,Any]](json)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any particular reason why you are including two versions of `jerkson`, one for scala 2.10 and one for scala 2.9.1.  This is generally a bad idea.

Comment: No, I added the 2.10 version since I'm using scala 2.10. However, moving to only one does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` generally means there is some sort of issues with the classpath.  For starters, if you are running on scala 2.10, I would remove the following line from your `sbt` file:

```
"com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.5.0"
```

Then, make sure the `com.cloudphysics` jerkson jar file is available in your apps classpath and try your test again.

Comment: leads to NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest

Comment: Can you post your build.sbt file

Comment: adding the sonatype repository fixed it.